# How can I get all combinations of selecting one element from each list?

Tags: python

Suppose I have 4 lists.

```
group = [1]
question_number = [1,2,20,22,34,36]
response = range(1,6)
score = range(100,-1,-25)
```

I'd like to get all tuples of selecting one element from each list.

```
(1,1,1,100)
(1,1,1,75)
...
(1,36,5,0)
```

I could do this with  loop, but I am wondering if itertools has something easier?  I know `itertools.combinations` can get all combos of length `n`.  Is there a similar function for multiple lists?

Answer (score 1):

I forgot this was called the Cartesian product.  I used `itertools.product` to get what I wanted.